# How to know when there is a selected text in a text area instead of polling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Blog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.interval = null;
    this.selectionStartIndex = null;
    this.selectionEndIndex = null;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setSelectionIndexes(document.activeElement);
    }, 100);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  setBlog = (blog, cb) =>
    this.setState({ blog }, () => {
      this.code.innerHTML = blog;
      cb && cb();
  });

  setSelectionIndexes = elem => {
    if (elem.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') {
      this.selectionStartIndex = elem.selectionStart;
      this.selectionEndIndex = elem.selectionEnd;
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (

      <TextArea
        value={blog}
        onChange={e => this.setBlog(e.target.value)}
        rows={8}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm doing a markdown editor. In SO I found a question on how to get the selected values from a text area. As you can see in the method it uses setInterval to continually check if there is a selected text, but I'm some how frustrated to using this method to get the selected text in a text area. Is there a better way like an event to know when there is a selected text in a text area instead of polling?

Comment: check on mouseup of the textarea? And on keyup for when people are selecting with the keyboard... Not tried, but it might work.

Comment: has your question been answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
    var aEl = document.activeElement;
    var aElTagName = aEl ? aEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
    if (aElTagName == "textarea") {
        alert(aEl.value.slice(aEl.selectionStart, aEl.selectionEnd));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the mechanism there:

```
onChange={e => this.setBlog(e.target.value)}
```

I imagine setBlog() is some kind of state store? And if it isn't, just use setState() to store that value. (you haven't got it in the code you posted). Why not just check the value in the store?

Comment: You can check setBlog() now, but I don't think onChange will work.